# Recursive descent parser in PHP

Tags: php, recursive-descent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an alternative for flex/bison that is usable on 8-bit embedded systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems)

I wanted to make this parser for a long time now, but I don't even know where to start from. Those parser scripts are nowhere close to be clear to me, so any tutorial for beginners would come in handy. I have more than enough experience in PHP to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: See <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163">my SO answer on how to build recursive descent parsers</a> in general. This will work for PHP just fine, if you have a relatively straightforward
language to parse. If your language is complex, you might want to consider a parser generator.

Comment: As far as I see, the syntax is not hard at all. I am a beginner in this though. It means I neither now how to start a parser, nor how to make it going on. What I can figure out is to split the parsing file in characters, and then just check if the right character is where it should be.

Comment: That's good enough, you can write a parser that processes individual characters.  I suggest you write a very simple one first to get experience, before you tackle your actual goal.